# How to fix a "Failed to fetch binary-armhf/Packages" error during apt-get update?

Tags: apt, arm

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried looking in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to see if anything in that directory can be removed but all that is in there is

```
nodesource.list
nodesource.list.save
```

In my `sources.list` file I have:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Can anyone recommend a way of fixing this error?

Comment: Looks like there is a malformed line in the /etc/apt/sources.list file. You may want to post it for review.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever I've edited my question with the contents of `sources.list`

Comment: The last two lines don't belong there. They are for x86 packages, and don't have armf versions.

Comment: @mikewhatever removing those two seems to have fixed the error. If you want to add an answer I can give you some credit?

Comment: @henrywright All done. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offending line was from the x86 source list. Removing it eliminated the error. The following is the correct list for armf architecture.

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main
```

Answer (score 24):

You might install the `armhf` cross tools which add `armhf` as foreign architecture (your architecture maybe i386 or amd64). You can launch this command to verify:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

If the output includes `armhf`, you can simply remove it by running the command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```

Finally, launch your `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: `armhf` is my architecture actually so `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` outputs nothing.

Comment: OK, your question didn't mention that :)

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the answer though, it's certainly useful. +1 from me!

Comment: Woh!! Bravo. This is the solution to my problem. Update is running fine now. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to upvote my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this answer. I have the same problem and running the first line shows i386. So what do I do to fix it in that case?