# Gnome Tweak Tool Broken after partial upgrade - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome

Software Updater performed a partial upgrade today and removed the gnome-tweak-tool and I think one of the depencies - `gir1.2-handy-0.0`.  I've tried installing in the Terminal and with Synaptic, but I got a broken package error with both. Installed `gir1.2-handy-0.0`, but still get this error when installing the tweak tool:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-tweak-tool : Depends: gnome-tweaks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried:

1. Fixing the broken install

   ```
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   ```
2. Purging the tweak tool and reinstalling it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge gnome-tweak-tool
   sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
3. Installing the package from the Focal repository [gnome-tweaks (3.34.0-2ubuntu1) [universe]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/gnome-tweaks/download)

Still getting the same result.

Comment: What about `sudo dpkg --configure gnome-tweaks gome-tweak-tools` ?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-tweak-tool gnome-tweaks`?

Comment: @ B. du Garay - The result was: `dpkg: error processing package gnome-tweaks (--configure):
 no package named 'gnome-tweaks' is installed, cannot configure
dpkg: error processing package gnome-tweak-tools (--configure):
 no package named 'gnome-tweak-tools' is installed, cannot configure
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-tweaks
 gnome-tweak-tools`

Comment: @Kulfy - The output was:  `gnome-tweak-tool:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.34.0-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.34.0-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
gnome-tweaks:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.34.0-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.34.0-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages`

Comment: What do you get when you try to install GNOME Tweaks using `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`?

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-tweaks : Depends: gnome-shell-extension-prefs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Comment: And what about `apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-prefs; sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`?

Comment: `$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell-extension-prefs
gnome-shell-extension-prefs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.36.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     3.36.1-5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     3.36.1-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages`

Comment: `$ sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:`

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: gnome-shell (= 3.36.1-5ubuntu2) but 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.36.1-5ubuntu2) but 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: What about `apt-cache policy gnome-shell gnome-shell-common`?

Comment: `$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1
  Candidate: 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages`
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.36.1-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: `gnome-shell-common:
  Installed: 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1
  Candidate: 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 Version table:
 *** 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.36.1-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help @Kulfy.  I figured it out. The repositories were not able to be accessed during a software update due to `E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-armhf/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]` and while researching that problem, it lead me to this post:
[How to fix a "Failed to fetch binary-armhf/Packages" error during apt-get update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705895/how-to-fix-a-failed-to-fetch-binary-armhf-packages-error-during-apt-get-update)

Ran `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf` as instructed in that thread and was able to update.  One problem solved.  Then figured I'd try installing Gnome Tweaks to see if there was any relation and it worked.